# How to exclude folders in Tortoise Check-ins

Tags: tortoisesvn

I see in the settings you can specify patterns to exclude files from check-ins.  But how would you add to include folders bin and obj?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add this in the same place you exclude the files:

*/bin */obj

Answer (score 16):

I use Settings\Global Ignore Pattern. 
This is what I have added to the default list:

```
*.suo *.user bin obj Debug Release _UpgradeReport_Files *.dbmdl
```

Answer (score 1):

The svn:ignore property will ignore matching files and folders. This is what I have to exclude bin and obj folders 
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
Make sure to check the "Apply Property recursively"

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the bin directory and select TortoiseSVN > Add to Ignore List > *FolderName*. Then do the same thing for obj.

Comment: The downside to doing it this way is that you'll have to do it for every project you have.