# How to ignore folders when committing the code, so they should not come up

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN and I don't use command line. Would be appreciate if someone please instruct me using GUI

how to ignore certain folders to no to show when I am committing. For example in the image below how can I ignore the media folder to no to show at anytime when I am committing the code.

I tried putting it into ignore list. But after that it always show a big red cross on my parent folder. I don't want to see that and want to see green arrow if the repo is upto date and including ignored folder.

Everytime I have to be careful when I am committing the code so that I should not push any cache or unwanted material and manually uncheck sometimes. Please suggest

Thanks alot.

[image]

Comment: Other possible duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182492/how-do-i-configure-the-tortoisesvn-global-ignore-pattern-properly),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/778715/how-to-exclude-folders-in-tortoise-check-ins),[3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257488/tortoise-is-it-possible-to-ignore-new-folder-before-committing-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the global ignore list instead (via the TortoiseSVN settings).